# Play audio tag with blob inside on mobile

Tags: php, html, audio, blob, html5-audio

i've made this script:

```
<?php 
if(!empty($dati['audio'])) { ?>
    <span>
       <audio id="audio_player" src="data:audio/mp3;base64,<?php echo base64_encode($dati['audio']);?>"  controls="controls" autobuffer="autobuffer">
       </audio>
    </span>
<?php } ?>
```

It create an audio tag with a blob value inside..it work in every browser on pc but it won't work on some mobile browser..i've tried with external library to play audio in different way but it look like no one allow blob instead of the path of the file..someone have an idea which can help me to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace `data:audio/mp3` to `data:audio/mpeg`

This [link](http://fettblog.eu/blog/2012/04/08/html5-audio-on-mobile-devices/) will be useful too.

If not working. Try this onle also.

```
<audio id="audioFile" controls="controls" loop="loop" autoplay="autoplay" >
   <source src="filename.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
   <source src="filename.ogg" type="audio/ogg" />
</audio>
```

Hope it will work for you :)

Comment: In which OS, you are checking?

Comment: Android, it work on asus zenfone with stock browser, but won't work on galaxy s6. In chrome mobile it won't work. In safari on ios 9.2 it work.